# r sort hexadecimal to reverse colour palette

Tags: r, image, sorting, color-palette

I would like to plot with `image.plot` from the `fields` package using the default palette in reverse order. In the help page it says

> Color table to use for image ( see help file on image for details). Default is a pleasing range of 64 divisions suggested by Tim Hoar and is similar to the MATLAB (TM) jet color scheme.

So I figured out the easiest way was to sort in decreasing order, problem is the vector of colour is in hexadecimal, how do you do it? convert in decimal and then convert it back? Is there an easier/more intelligent way to go?

Comment: Sort in decreasing order of what? Colours don't have a natural ordering. If you just want to reverse the palette, use `col=rev(tim.colors(64))`

Comment: I knew there was a supereasy way to go! Thanks! If you can make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`image.plot` in `fields` uses:

```
col = tim.colors(nlevel)
```

so simply use:

```
col = rev(tim.colors(64))
```

in your call to `image.plot` - change the 64 to whatever `nlevel` you want.

[Note that rainbow colour palettes aren't always the best choice anyway...]

Comment: Thanks for the tip at the end I opted for a sequential palette using RColorBrewer